# HTML Table Sizing Issues

Tags: html, css, html-table

What I have is a table that I would like to be placed in the center of the page with two banner ads on both sides of the table, the left and right ads coming as close to the edges of the page as possible with maybe a 5px margin. I already have that in place, but I would like the table to get as close to the ads as well. What is happening is that dependent on the screen resolution, the table is either too big, thus moving the ad to the next line, or if on an 11-inch screen the table is way too small.

I have taken a screenshot of my issue and can be found here:

[image: i.imgur.com/SCypuj2.png].

The issue is, that if you look at the ad on the right, it is far away from the table, but that changes due to screen resolution. if it was a small monitor it would either be perfect, or would be too small and push the ad to the next line.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left-ad">[adsense stuff]</div>
<table class="tl">
    <tr>
        <th width="100%" colspan="3">Filename</th>
        <th>Size&nbsp;
            <img src="./images/icons/size.gif" alt="Sort" />

        </th>
        <th>Downloaded&nbsp;
            <img src="./images/icons/down.png">
        </th>
        <th>Date Added&nbsp;
            <img src="./images/icons/added.png">
        </th>
    </tr>
<div class="right-ad">[adsense stuff]</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .left-ad {
     float: left;
     width: 160px;
     min-height: 100px;
     padding-left: 10px;
 }
 .right-ad {
     float: right;
     width: 160px;
     min-height: 100px;
     padding-right: 10px;
 }
 table.tl {
     display: inline;
     float: left;
     min-height: 100px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     width: 71%;
 }
```

I have also updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZgpe/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code, you need,(copy - paste it and see result in browser.)

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
     <HEAD>
      <style>
     .left-ad {
         float: left;
         width: 94px;
         min-height: 500px;
         padding-left: 10px;
         border:1px solid black;
     }
     .right-ad {
         float: right;
         width: 160px;
         min-height: 500px;
         padding-right: 10px;
         border:1px solid black;
     }
     table.tl {
         display: inline;
         float: left;
         min-height: 100px;
         padding: 0 10px;
         width: 71%;
     }
      </style>
     </HEAD>

     <BODY>
      <div class="left-ad">[adsense stuff]</div>
    <table class="tl" border = "1">
        <tr>
            <th width="100%" colspan="3">Filename</th>
            <th>Size&nbsp;
                <img src="./images/icons/size.gif" alt="Sort" />

            </th>
            <th>Downloaded&nbsp;
                <img src="./images/icons/down.png">
            </th>
            <th>Date Added&nbsp;
                <img src="./images/icons/added.png">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <div class="right-ad">[adsense stuff]</div>

     </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: yes, I test it and its work fine with me,
left and right side add and your data in center.
Try it. copy and paste whole code @ralph.m

Comment: That's what I did, and it doesn't work. You may be just testing it at one width. Resize your browser window and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, I actually forgot it to check in different size,
thanks for that @ralph.m

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach it would be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
.wrap {position: relative;}
.left-ad, .right-ad {width: 160px; height: 200px; background: gray; position: absolute; top: 0;}
.left-ad {left: 10px;}
.right-ad {right: 10px;}
table {margin-left: 180px; margin-right: 180px; background: blue;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left-ad">[adsense stuff]</div>

    <table class="tl">
        <tr>
            <th width="100%" colspan="3">Filename</th>
            <th>Size&nbsp;
                <img src="./images/icons/size.gif" alt="Sort" />

            </th>
            <th>Downloaded&nbsp;
                <img src="./images/icons/down.png">
            </th>
            <th>Date Added&nbsp;
                <img src="./images/icons/added.png">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="right-ad">[adsense stuff]</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```